# How to install xcode 11.7 in external ssd

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I want to install xcode in an external drive because it takes too much space in the mac storage(128g version).

I have unpacked xcode.xip in the external drive and moved the Developer folder as well to `myssd/Library/Developer`, and then added a symlink using `ln -s /Volumes/myssd/Library/Developer /Users/myUserName/Library/`.

Now xcode is not detecting simulators and i cant add new ones.

[image]

**Edit**:
if i run xcode using  :
`sudo /Volumes/PNYPROELITE/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`
the simulators are detected but when the app is launched i see only the icon of the simulator in the dock not the simulator itself.

Comment: Have you found solution to this question?

Comment: No, I just installed back Xcode in main drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for this is to install another macOs session in the external drive and then boot in it, then install Xcode there like you would in your normal drive.